# How do i get a string to get an integer that is inside a method

Tags: java, string, integer

I have created an example class for my problem below.

```
    public class testClass {

     public void testMethod()
     {
         int testInteger = 5;
     }

     String testString = "Hello World" +  testInteger;

}
```

I have an integer inside a method and a string that is in no method as seen above. I want the string to get the integer that inside the method but it cannot. Can someone please help explain why that is so and tell me how to make the string the integer. thanks.

Comment: You can't do it because it doesn't make any sense.  Can you explain what you expect to happen?  What should `testString` before you call the method and after it?

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down your code to see what is going on

you have such a function

```
 public void testMethod()
 {
     int testInteger = 5;
 }
```

as you see the return type is `void` so **nothing will be return** to anywhere that is called this method.

you have this line after your testMethod

```
String testString = "Hello World" + testInteger;
```

first it looks odd why?

because you do not have any main method so I do not know how your code runs

but Imagine you have main method like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     String testString = "Hello World" + testInteger;
 }
```

second, you did not even call your testMethod in order to utilize it inside your main method 
**Issues**

> **1**. you did not call your `testMethod` at all
>
> **2**. Even if you called it, it would not help you because your return type is `void`
>
> **3**. you need main method in order your code to be ran

**Remedies**

**1**. change your return type to int

your function signature:

```
public int testMethod()
```

**2**. if you want to use your method, you have to use it in your main method like

for example:

```
String testString = "Hello World" + testMethod();
```

**3**. do not forget to have your main method because it is necessary for your code to be ran

your main method signature is

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the askers question.

Comment: @1337 than k you does it look better?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
public class testClass {

     public int testMethod()
     {
         int testInteger = 5;
         return testInteger;
     }

    String testString = "Hello World" + testMethod();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The integer is a variable inside the method; it has scope of the method which means it can't be accessed from outside the method.  The String is a field; it has scope of the class, so it can be accessed from anywhere inside the class including inside the method.

Comment: Yeah, you have to return the integer from the method or use a member variable. Funny question, though

Answer (score 0):

It's basic Java... the testInteger is defined in the method so not available out of the method. You could let the method return an int (being your testInteger) and call that method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a local variable from another method without returning it.

```
public int testMethod()
{
  int testInteger = 5;
  return testInteger;
}
```

Then you can get the value by calling the method (assuming you have an instance of your class in a reference `instance`),

```
String testString = "Hello World" + instance.testMethod();
```

From [The Java Tutorials: Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html),

> Local Variables Similar to how an object stores its state in fields, a method will often store its temporary state in local variables. The syntax for declaring a local variable is similar to declaring a field (for example, int count = 0;). There is no special keyword designating a variable as local; that determination comes entirely from the location in which the variable is declared — which is between the opening and closing braces of a method. As such, local variables are only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible from the rest of the class.